# Is this a good way to create a dynamic webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, dynamic, redirect

I'm trying to create a dynamic webpage using `include()` in PHP.
This PHP page has the following codes - literally, that's all the file contains:

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbName = $_REQUEST['DBName'];
$tbName = $_REQUEST['TBName'];
$dbType = $_REQUEST['DBType'];

include('header.php');
switch($dbType)
{
    case 'Calender':
        include('CalenderPage.php');
        exit;
    case 'News':
        include('NewsPage.php');
        exit;
    case 'Gallery':
        include('GalleryPage.php');
        exit;
}
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Do you think it's a good way of creating dynamic PHP page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yike... sorry people. I thought my question was appropriate to be posted. Thank you for the comments. Should I delete this question? I will if needed : )

Comment: No need to delete it a mod will probably migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show is perfectly fine. It could be done a bit simpler using an array:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Explicitly using $_GET or $_POST is better than $_REQUEST
$dbName = $_GET['DBName'];
$tbName = $_GET['TBName'];
$dbType = $_GET['DBType'];

include('header.php');

// be sure to have an array of allowed pages 
// so people can't access pages they're not supposed to access
$allowed_pages = array("Calender", "News", "Gallery");

if (in_array($dbType, $allowed_pages))
 include($dbType."Page.php");
else
 die("Unknown page");

include('footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like the the `include()` function to create dynamic php page. I find it very difficult to avoid variables beeing conflicted in different php files. Let say that in `NewsPage.php` file you will change `$dbName`, it could result some problems in your main page and you might not realize what went wrong.

I only include files with classes/functions, that way i can control what code is beeing executed in the included php files, and it's more easy to debug my code.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and advices :)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine for starters, but notice your DRY issue, each page you'll add, you will write another 3 lines.
It'll be impossible to maintain it this way.
I see you got a name convention between the dbType and page, try :

```
include($dbType + 'Page.php');
```

instead of switch block

Comment: PHP uses `.` rather than `+` for concatenation.

Comment: If you did, please consider that it would open up the code to url injection. Hence a map or switch is indeed the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The name for this style of page is a template. It seems as valid as any other way to choose which content to display.